# exp = lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Width) What does this mean?

Tags: r

I am learning machine learning, I was reading about MICE package in R in one of the reference links. but struck at one point. I need somebody who can help in at this moment.

Here is the code, I have missing values in Sepal.Length,Sepal.width,Petal.Length,Petal.width in Iris.mis data frame.

So Author coded as below.

```
imputed_Data <- mice(iris.mis, m=5, maxit = 50, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)
```

we get 5 complete data sets, as mentioned m=5. And the next is with function, in order to combine 5 data sets. So,

```
fit <- with(data = iris.mis, exp = lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Width))
```

So, just wanted  what exactly is " exp = lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Width)) "

I understand, Author is using linear regression by lm, but what is the purpose of regression over here. Why is he doing it?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are only interesting in the author's intent, then you should ask them. That's on odd thing to for others to guess about.

Comment: I do understand, this doesn't much of programming, I did post in that website. I didnt get any comments for this. So to clear out my doubts, i took this as platform. I wanted understand, what exactly are they doing.

Answer (score 2):

Read `help("with")`. There is a parameter `expr` (which expects an expression). R allows partial name matching for function arguments. Thus, `exp` is matched to the `expr` parameter.

This is really a convoluted alternative to the much better `fit <- lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Width, data = iris.mis)`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, But why did author took only Sepal.width as dependent and Sepal.Length and Petal.Width as independent? and why didn't he consider Petal.Length? any guesses, and why is he taking liner regression??? Thanks again.

Comment: They simply demonstrate that you can do linear regression after the imputation. What you intend to do with the data set after imputation is upt to you, but usually you use some kind of statistical model.